# Como consultar um vetor de structs em C depois de já ter escrito nele?

Tags: c, banco-de-dados, ponteiro, struct

Olá, quero uma ajuda estou fazendo um programa que tem um menu o usuario cadastra e depois consulta o cadastro, o problema e que eu nao estou conseguindo consultar o "banco de dados" vetor de structs.

O usuário se cadastra e redirecionado para o menu com uma mensagem de cadastro completo, logo apos ele escolhe consultar o seu cadastro o programa pede o nome do usuario e usa a biblioteca string para ver se o cadastro existe a princípio a ideia e só printa na tela "usuário existente" depois em incremento o restante.

porém quando o usuário digita o nome ele e automaticamente redirecionado para a função exit() PORQUE?

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RET 0

int qc = 1;

void menu(void);
int cadastrar(void);
void consultar(void);
void sair(void);

struct usuarios{
  char nome[30];
  int idade;
  int user;
};

int main(void)
{
  menu();
  return(RET);
}

void menu(void)
{
  int esc;
  retorno:
  printf("------------------------------------\n"
        "|  Sistema de cadastro de cliente  |\n"
        "------------------------------------\n");
  printf("====MENU=======\n"
        "1.Cadastrar   |\n"
        "2.Consultar   |\n"
        "0.Sair        |\n");
  printf("===============\n\n");
  printf("opção: ");
  scanf(" %d", &esc);
  switch(esc){
    case 1:
    cadastrar();
    case 2:
    consultar();
    case 0:
    sair();
    default:
    system("clear");
    printf("Digito invalido\n\n");
    goto retorno;
  }
}

int cadastrar()
{
  int ind;
  system("clear");
  printf("------------------------");
  printf("\n| Cadastro de usuarios |\n");
  printf("------------------------\n");
  printf("Quantos usuarios quer cadastrar? ");
  scanf("%d", &qc);
  struct usuarios info_user[qc];
  struct usuarios *ptr[qc];
  system("clear");
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
      ptr[ind] = &info_user[ind];
      ptr[ind]->user = 1;
  }
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
    ptr[ind] = &info_user[ind];
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("|  Cadastrando usuario  |\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr[ind]->nome);
    printf("Digite sua idade: ");
    scanf("%d", &ptr[ind]->idade);
    ptr[ind] -> user++;
    system("clear");
  }
  if(qc == 1){
    printf("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!\n\n");
  }
  else if(qc > 1){
    printf("Usuarios cadastrados com sucesso!\n\n");
  }
  menu();
  return(RET);
}

void consultar()
{
  char nomeu[30];
  int comp;
  int ind;
  struct usuarios info_user[qc];
  struct usuarios *ptr[qc];
  system("clear");
  printf("-------------------------\n"
        "|  Consultando usuario  |\n"
        "-------------------------\n");
  printf("\nDigite o nome do usuario: ");
  scanf("%s", nomeu);
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
    ptr[ind] = &info_user[ind];
  }
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
    comp = strcmp(nomeu, ptr[ind] -> nome);
    if(comp == 1){
      printf("User existente");
    }
  }
}

void sair()
{
  printf("Encerrando programa...");
  exit(0);
}```
````

Comment: Reveja o funcionamento do comando switch/case. Da maneira como você fez caso seja informado 1 ele irá executar: `cadastrar();` seguido de `consultar();` seguido de `sair();` seguido de `system("clear"); printf("Digito invalido\n\n"); goto retorno;` e, desconfio você não queira executar tudo isso. Outra coisa a estudar é o escopo de variáveis. Você declarou `struct usuarios` com escopo global mas declarou `info_user[qc]` com escopo local à função, isto é quando sair da função `cadastrar` este array deixará de existir. Em `consultar` seu array não tem dados (na realidade tem lixo de memória).

Comment: Outra coisa: não entendi o motivo da utilização de um array de ponteiros para `struct usuarios`, talvez uma confusão de conceitos.

Answer (score 1):

O programa tem vários erros de estruturação, a forma como você está usando o operador `switch` que está causando esse problema a que você se refere na sua pergunta. esse operador tem o seguinte funcionamento:

```
switch(variable){
  case 1:
    Func_1() // Essa função vai ser executada se variable == 1
  case 2:
    Func() // Essa função vai ser executada se variable == 1 ou variable == 2
}
```

Para contornar esse funcionamento e fazer seu programa funcionar da forma que deveria você deve utilizar o `break` logo após cada instrução de case:

```
switch(variable){
  case 1:
    Func_1(); // Essa função vai ser executada se variable == 1
    break;
  case 2:
    Func(); // Essa função vai ser executada se variable == 2
    break;
}
```

Além disso você não criou os usuários de forma global, então logo que acaba a função cadastra() aquele usuário cadastrado é perdido e na função consulta() você está criando outro banco de usuários somente. O programa chama a função exit(0) logo após a tentativa de busca pois nunca vai encontrar o usuário e em seguida pelo funcionamento do switch ele retorna para o menu() a partir daquele ponto e executa o código em 'case 0'.
O motivo de um erro semelhante não ocorrer com a função cadastrar() está sendo porque você chama um novo menu no fim dela, dessa forma você está criando uma pilha de menus, o que causará falhas no desempenho conforme o programa continua rodando.

Answer (score 0):

O problema do break eu já resolvi, mas como eu posso declarar as variáveis com vetores do tipo struct e um ponteiro com a mesma quantidade de vetor, e inicializar cada ponteiro apontando para um vetor da estrutura de forma global para que eu consiga utilizar eu outras funções? se tiver como reescreve-lo para mim e explicar, Mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda valeu.

Obs: O motivo de eu querer usar ponteiros, é porque é o que eu estou aprendendo no momento, geralmente eu crio programas complexos que nao tem a menor necessidade apenas para fixar. Mas se por a caso não tiver como usar os ponteiros não tem problema

O codigo atual está assim:

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RET 0

int qc = 1;

void menu(void);
int cadastrar(void);
void consultar(void);
void sair(void);

struct usuarios{
  char nome[30];
  int idade;
  int user;
};

int main(void)
{
  menu();
  return(RET);
}

void menu(void)
{
  int esc;
  retorno:
  printf("------------------------------------\n"
        "|  Sistema de cadastro de cliente  |\n"
        "------------------------------------\n");
  printf("====MENU=======\n"
        "1.Cadastrar   |\n"
        "2.Consultar   |\n"
        "0.Sair        |\n");
  printf("===============\n\n");
  printf("opção: ");
  scanf(" %d", &esc);
  switch(esc){
    case 1:
    cadastrar();
    break;
    case 2:
    consultar();
    break;
    case 0:
    sair();
    break;
    default:
    system("clear");
    printf("Digito invalido\n\n");
    goto retorno;
  }
}

int cadastrar()
{
  int ind;
  system("clear");
  printf("------------------------");
  printf("\n| Cadastro de usuarios |\n");
  printf("------------------------\n");
  printf("Quantos usuarios quer cadastrar? ");
  scanf("%d", &qc);
  struct usuarios info_user[qc];
  struct usuarios *ptr[qc];
  system("clear");
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
      ptr[ind] = &info_user[ind];
      ptr[ind]->user = 1;
  }
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
    ptr[ind] = &info_user[ind];
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("|  Cadastrando usuario  |\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr[ind]->nome);
    printf("Digite sua idade: ");
    scanf("%d", &ptr[ind]->idade);
    ptr[ind] -> user++;
    system("clear");
  }
  if(qc == 1){
    printf("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!\n\n");
  }
  else if(qc > 1){
    printf("Usuarios cadastrados com sucesso!\n\n");
  }
  menu();
  return(RET);
}

void consultar()
{
  char nomeu[30];
  int comp;
  int ind;
  struct usuarios info_user[qc];
  struct usuarios *ptr[qc];
  system("clear");
  printf("-------------------------\n"
        "|  Consultando usuario  |\n"
        "-------------------------\n");
  printf("\nDigite o nome do usuario: ");
  scanf("%s", nomeu);
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
    ptr[ind] = &info_user[ind];
  }
  for(ind=0;ind<qc;ind++){
    comp = strcmp(nomeu, ptr[ind] -> nome);
    if(comp == 1){
      printf("User existente");
    }
  }
}

void sair()
{
  printf("Encerrando programa...");
  exit(0);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

É só declarar esse trecho uma única vez fora de qualquer método, igual fez com a variável "qc":

```
int qc = 1;
struct usuarios info_user[qc];
struct usuarios *ptr[qc];
```

Do jeito que você está utilizando os ponteiros nesse programa não tem utilidade nenhuma, mas para este programa você vai precisar usar ponteiros (`struct usuarios *ptr`) e fazer alocação dinâmica de usuários (pesquise as funções `malloc` e `realloc`) ou então fazer esse banco de usuário ter um valor teto alto de usuários e você vai escrevendo nele (`struct usuarios users[1000]`). Não vou reescrever o código corrigindo todos esses problemas porque vai ter que rever muitos funcionamentos de loops que já estão feitos mas é dessa forma que você vai conseguir resolvê-los.